# How do I make the TreeViewItem(s) of an existing TreeView raise a Click event?

Tags: wpf, treeview

How do I make the TreeViewItem(s) of an existing WPF TreeView raise a Click event?

Currently, we are handling the SelectedItemChanged. In our case, we are displaying dialogs, so the user may click on the same selected TreeViewItem multiple times.

Comment: A click in MouseLeftButtonUp not MouseLeftButtonDown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Working Sample

```
<Window x:Class="MenuExperiment1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <TreeView Name="treeView1"
              Height="320"
              Width="200">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp"
                             Handler="treeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp" />
                <EventSetter Event="KeyUp"
                             Handler="treeViewItem_KeyUp" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem  Header="aa" />
        <TreeViewItem  Header="bb">
            <TreeViewItem Header="b1"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="b2"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem  Header="cc">
            <TreeViewItem Header="c1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="c1a"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="c1b"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="c2"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem  Header="dd" />
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MenuExperiment1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void treeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Handler(sender,e);
        }

        private void treeViewItem_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                Handler(sender, e);
            }
        }

        private void Handler(object sender, InputEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Debug.Write(((TreeViewItem)sender).Header);
            Debug.WriteLine(" clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the MouseLeftButtonUp event? You should be able to achieve the same UX by hooking to that event as you would with an actual click event.

[PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttondown.aspx) and [MouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown.aspx) may also work for you depending on the layout of your TreeViewItems (such as using a content template containing a TextBlock for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event setter in the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `TreeView`:

```
      <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Using `ItemContainerStyle` doesn't work for child items. Moving to Resources works.